# Can't connect to Flask web service, connection refused

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to run a simple web server on a Raspberry Pi with Flask. When I run my Flask app, it says:

> running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/

But when I enter this address on my laptop's in Chrome, I get

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I can open 127.0.0.1:5000 on the Raspberry Pi's browser. What do I need to do to connect from another computer?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the localhost address and will only be reachable from the raspi. In order to get access from your laptop open up the terminal on your raspi and try instead the ip from `ifconfig` should look something like 192.168.0.XX:5000. This assumes that they are both on the same local network.

Comment: @jm_____ `ifconfig` returned 192.168.1.103, I tried it with `:5000` but still get connection refused. and yes they are both on the same network

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Run your app like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

It will make the server [externally visible](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#public-server). If the IP address of the machine is `192.168.X.X` then, from the same network you can access it in 5000 port. Like, http://192.168.X.X:5000

Comment: If you want to access the app from the same machine use `http://127.0.0.1:5000` still though

Comment: For those looking for how to do this with socketio: socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0')

Comment: I have been looking for the answer half day. Finally, I found it. Thank you very much.

Comment: For some reason `flask run --host=0.0.0.0` works but `app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)` and `flask run` doesn't on Windows.

Comment: @Sankalp What I have inferred for your problem is that when you run `flask run`, the `__name__` is not `'__main__'`. So, the server starts but not as per the arguments you pass in `app.run()`. While in `flask run --host=0.0.0.0`, the host is explicitly specified.

Comment: @Sankalp Another way to do so is by running `python <name of your serverfile>.py` - this will run the server with the arguments provided by you (Why? Simply because this time `__name__` is `'__main__'`).

Comment: @paradoxlover: Thanks for the suggestions. Both solutions worked for me (Flask application running in a VirtualBox Linux VM on Windows 10 host. Bridged network option used.). I added the details because it took me a long time to find this problem. Maybe the comments will help others reach this hint faster. (of course flask server is only for the first check of the flask app on the VM... it would be needed to use something else like gunicorn later)

Comment: for some unknown reason, i was able to access flask server webpage from another computer, but not from my android smartphone browser. any clue?

Comment: @agenis Make sure your smartphone is in the same network.

Answer (score 17):

when you are running the server via `flask run` change it to `flask run --host=0.0.0.0`
to connect, find the IPV4 address of the server that your script is running on. On the same network, go to `http://[IPV4 address]:5000`

Comment: For some reason `flask run --host=0.0.0.0` works but `app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)` and `flask run` doesn't on Windows.

Answer (score 15):

A reason could also be in **firewall** refusing incoming connections on port 5000. Try:

```
sudo ufw allow 5000
```

Comment: Raspberry Pi does not come with `ufw`

Answer (score 7):

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)
```

if you run your app in this way then your server will be visible externally.
Steps by Setp:

1. Run your app by using the following command

   **app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)**
2. Go to the window cmd . Type **ipconfig** and get the get the IPV4 adress suppose your IPV4 address is 192.168.X.X
3. Go to the mobile browser and type the   **192.168.X.X:5000**

Comment: Why do I have to use the IPv4 address and not use the localhost address?

Comment: @AlexF I cannot justify because I am not a flask developer. But this configuration works for me when I was working on the project.

Comment: @Alex_F localhost address is ONLY either 127.0.0.1 or localhost. The IP address 0.0.0.0 has a special meaning - "run on all available IP addresses". The Flask port being 5000 is just standard for whatever reason that I do not know.

Answer (score 5):

If you  have `debug = True` inside your `app.run()`, then it will not be visible to other machines either. Specify *host* and *port* inside `app.run()` without the `debug = True`.

Comment: This is not correct. An app run in debug mode can be seen by other computers on the network provided `host='0.0.0.0'` as in other answers to this question

Answer (score 2):

You will have to run the development server such that it listens to requests on all interfaces and not just the local one

Ask Flask to listen on `0.0.0.0:PORT_NUMBER`

or any other port you may choose

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS 12.4 (Monterey) I couldn't load localhost nor my local IP but it worked with both of these:

- 0.0.0.0
- 127.0.0.1

Just change the URL in the browser if it loads with "localhost".

Answer (score 0):

- Both devices must be connected to same network.
- Use `app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)` and run with your own Ipv4
  address like his http://[Your Ipv4 address]:5000
- If you are    connecting this with android app then don't forget to
  put INTERNET    permission in manifest file.

Comment: Hi, I still have the same issue. even though I tried will all ipv4 addres2, 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.1, localhost everything.. still couldn't connect flutetr to flask backend on localhost :/. Can you tell how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to popular believe 127.0.0.1 is not the same a localhost.
I solved the issue above by setting 127.0.0.1 explicitly on both ends.

Answer (score 0):

In your API call, use the IP address of the machine your server is hosted on instead of localhost.

Answer (score -1):

Well i was also here to know answer but i guess i found out problem. The reason is that you may not activated or run flask that's why it is showing error. For that you have to start from terminal "flask run" and then surely your flask will run...

Answer (score -2):

The issue may occur, if VPN is on, so try to switch it off.