# Cannot see my web application using Docker container

Tags: python, web-applications, docker, flask, docker-compose

I am trying to test my web application using a docker container, but I am not able to see it when I try to access it through my browser.

The docker compose file looks like

```
version: '2'
services:
db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
        - ~/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    environment:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "dbpassword"
        PGDATA: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
web:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile-web
    ports:
        - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
        - ./web:/web
    depends_on:
        - db
backend:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile-backend
    volumes:
        - ./backend:/backend
    depends_on:
        - db
```

The dockerfile-web looks like

```
FROM python
ADD web/requirements.txt /web/requirements.txt
ADD web/bower.json /web/bower.json
WORKDIR /web

RUN \
  wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.4.7/node-v4.4.7-linux-x64.tar.xz && \
  tar xJf node-*.tar.xz -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 && \
  rm -f node-*.tar.xz

RUN npm install -g bower
RUN bower install --allow-root

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN export MYFLASKAPP_SECRET='makethewebsite'

CMD python manage.py server
```

The ip for my docker machine is

docker-machine ip
192.168.99.100

But when I try 
http://192.168.99.100:5000/
in my browser it just says that the site cannot be reached.
It seems like it is refusing the connection.

When I ping my database in the browser I can see that my database response in a log
http://192.168.99.100:5432/

So I tried wget inside the container and got

```
$ docker exec 3bb5246a0623 wget http://localhost:5000/
--2016-07-23 05:25:16--  http://localhost:5000/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:5000... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:5000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 34771 (34K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.1’

0K .......... .......... .......... ...                  100% 5.37M=0.006s

2016-07-23 05:25:16 (5.37 MB/s) - ‘index.html.1’ saved [34771/34771]
```

Anyone know how I can get my web application to show up through my browser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to Flask web service, connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554702/cant-connect-to-flask-web-service-connection-refused)

Answer (score 0):

I had to enable external visibility for my flask application.
You can see it here
[Can't connect to Flask web service, connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554702/cant-connect-to-flask-web-service-connection-refused)

Comment: Can you please provide a summary of the content in that link? It would be very helpful for other users.