# Unable to Connect with Flask in python

Tags: python, flask

I have a python chatbot and I'm tryig to run the GUI of it by running it with flask, but I have tried various solutions for this post: [Can't connect to Flask web service, connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554702/cant-connect-to-flask-web-service-connection-refused).

In the end, none of the solutions managed to allow me to connect to the page. All the errors were displaying either `404 Not Found` or `Unable to Connect`.

The code is provided from the [sample codes](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-it-yourself-chatbot-api-with-keras-tensorflow-model-f6d75ce957a5) of a medium post which serves as a tutorial for me to learn. Any helps or solutions to guide me on the right way would be appreciated.

**The block that runs the flask code**:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/katana-ml/api/v1.0/assistant", methods=['POST'])

def classify():
    ERROR_THRESHOLD = 0.25

    sentence = request.json['sentence']
    # generate probabilities from the model
    input_data = pd.DataFrame([bow(sentence, words)],
    dtype=float, index=['input'])
    results = model.predict([input_data])[0]
    # filter out predictions below a threshold
    results = [[i,r] for i,r in enumerate(results) if r>ERROR_THRESHOLD]
    # sort by strength of probability
    results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return_list = []
    for r in results:
        return_list.append({"intent": classes[r[0]], "probability": str(r[1])})
    # return tuple of intent and probability
    response = jsonify(return_list)
    return response

# running REST interface, port=5000 for direct test, port=5001 for deployment from PM2
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Comment: How do you run the application? And did you export the entry point?

Comment: running it through the python file itself @J.G.

Comment: @User2382 did you try running it on 127.0.0.1 and connecting to 127.0.0.1:5000?

Comment: yes i did, i tried it on my mobile as well using IPv4 address @laundmo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined a POST method here.
If you access it on browser (like 127.0.0.1:5000), that would send a GET request.

Add a GET method for browser and use POST to access this method.

Comment: isnt that only related to the data that will be parsed through and back the form but it cant even display the webpage now.

Comment: @User2382, tanujabhoyar is right. To view this in a browser you will need to define a route with a GET method, as that his what the browser sends in the HTTP request. Otherwise use Postman to create a test for the POST url path: https://www.postman.com/