# Failed connection when running flask app on Linux server

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, web-development-server

I'm trying to deploy a flask app on a linux server. Currently, I'm testing it I'm try to run it with the following commands.

```
export FLASK_APP=main.py

flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

When I run this and try to navigate to [SERVER IP]:5000, there is a failed connection to the server. I've tried to implement solutions I've found elsewhere such as here:[Can't connect to Flask web service, connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554702/cant-connect-to-flask-web-service-connection-refused)

I've made these changes and it still does not work:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)
```

```
sudo ufw allow 5000
```

Some information about the server - Through linode running Ubuntu 21.04

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you connect to it locally telnet 127.0.0.1 5000 , (or curl) , if its working then try to find out why external connection not going through, may be firewall issue/ routing issue?

Comment: It does work locally. Again, I mentioned in the question that I enabled port 5000, so I assumed that that would resolve any firewall issues

Comment: Are you connect via a proxy ?  can you telnet  telnet serverip 5000 from another server ? ping from another server to your flask app server ip and check the connectivity.

Answer (score 2):

You should execute main.py directly if you're using `__name__ == "__main__"`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)
```

Your `app.run()` call isn't executed when using `flask run`

It should run on port 5000 by default so there shouldn't be any need for that configuration.

Try `python3 main.py` as suggest above and share the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to run it as `python main.py` from the terminal?

or

```
python3 main.py
```